# video em html5 - como adicionar dois videos

Tags: html5

Queria fazer dois videos ficar rodando, um depois do outro, tentei do jeito abaixo mas não funcionou.
Tem como fazer isso?

```
<video width='400' height='300' controls loop>
   <source src='video.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
   <source src='video2.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

Comment: você vai ter que fazer o controle por javascript, o encadeamento de source serve para fallback e não como playlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<video id="v1" width="320" height="240" controls="controls" onended="vidplay(2)">
<source src="http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/bkaovAYt-52qL9xLP.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<object data="" width="320" height="240">
<embed width="320" height="240" src="Yes Bank Advertisment.mp4">
</object>
</video>

<video id="v2" width="320" height="240" controls="controls" onended="vidplay(1)">
<source src="http://content.bitsontherun.com/videos/bkaovAYt-52qL9xLP.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<object data="" width="320" height="240">
<embed width="320" height="240" src="Yes Bank Advertisment.mp4">
</object>
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">

var video = document.getElementById("v1");
video.play();

function vidplay(i) {

  var video = document.getElementById("v"+i);
  if (video.paused) {
    video.play();

  } else {
    video.pause();

  }

};

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Editei aqui e funciona perfeitamente, fica um rodando do lado do outro! um de cada vez, veja se te ajuda

Precisa fazer com que o javascript controle isso, usei a tag onended que realiza uma chamada a função quando termina o video

Comment: não é rodando um ao lado do outro, preciso que ao terminar um, já rode o outro na sequencia

Comment: ah entendi, então pera ai

Comment: Prontinho jovem! @Adriano